# Is it possible to call from Keras unsupported backend function directly from tensorflow?

Tags: keras

I am working to create a Keras custom layer. this layer needs to use a function that doesn't exist in Keras TF backend, although it exist in TF.

What would be the best way to solve it?

1. Is there a way to call TF function directly from Keras and not from backend?
2. Should I work to modify backend to include a new unsupported function?

Any example or pointer how to implement the best solution.

Thank you

Comment: Does this solve the problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638053/using-custom-tensorflow-ops-in-keras ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no possible way to directly call tensorflow functions from keras. Keras is a stand-alone project. Although, tensorflow >= 1.12 has keras built in, so you could play with the source of tensorflow and figure it out.